# My JavaScript multi array that is a part of a larger multi array is not sorting based upon Boolean value in a Syncfusion VUE Data Grid

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ej2-syncfusion

I have a JSON object that has peoples names and a true and false item that asks if they are a contact. This is pulled from a Government API into a Vue application using a commercial Grid component from Syncfusion.  I'm pulling the api with axios.  Everything works fine except my sorting of object using code inside the Grid.  I starting to think I need to make a deep copy then sort.  This is the object as it is called from the api, it may not be perfectly formatted since I did a cut and paste

```
    "principal_investigators": [
    {
    "profile_id": 1873970,
    "first_name": "K",
    "middle_name": "T.",
    "last_name": "B",
    "is_contact_pi": false,
    "full_name": "K T. B",
    "title": null
    },
 {
    "profile_id": 1866589,
    "first_name": "F",
    "middle_name": "R",
    "last_name": "XL",
    "is_contact_pi": true,
    "full_name": "F R L",
    "title": null
    }
    {
    "profile_id": 1863489,
    "first_name": "F",
    "middle_name": "R",
    "last_name": "ZQ",
    "is_contact_pi": false,
    "full_name": "F R Z",
    "title": null
    }
    }]
```

It seems that inside the component in a browser watch all of the keys are in alpha order so is_contact_pi is in position third in the list.  I have tried deep cloning it 3 different ways.  It always stays in the original sort order and I have tried 2 different sort code.

```
principalInvestigators: function(field, data, column){       
       if(data["principal_investigators"] !=""){
         let aux = data["principal_investigators"]
       //  let clone = (items) => items.map(item => aux.isArray(item) ? clone(item) : item);
     //  let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aux));
       let clone = [...aux];
         console.log(aux)
         console.log(clone)
        console.log("first clone")
          // sort based upon is_contact_pi   is_contact_pi
        clone.sort(function (x, y) {     
        //return (y === x)? 0 : x[2]? 1 : -1;
        return (y[2] === x[2])? 0 : x[2]? 1 : -1;
        });

      //  let x = aux
        console.log(aux)

        console.log(clone)
        console.log("second clone")
        let principal =""
        for (var i = 0; i < clone.length; i++) { 
          principal += clone[i]["full_name"] + '\n'
        }
             return  principal    
       } else {
                 return ""   
         } 
     },
```

This maybe a question for Syncfusion and I may send it to them also tonight.  But does anyone think they have a solution or even a possible idea?  Build my principle string from 2 different loops?  One that is build from false and one that is build from true then join them?  I need to end up with the is contact first in the principal string with the rest following

Comment: There's no need to make a copy of `aux` before sorting.

Comment: The array elements are objects. There's no `[2]` element in the objects.

Comment: Which property are you trying to sort by?

Comment: `y[2]` should be `y.is_contact_pi`

Comment: so  return (y[2] === x[2])? 0 : x[2]? 1 : -1; should be  return (y.is_contact_pi  === x.is_contact_pi )? 0 : x.is_contact_pi ? 1 : -1;

Comment: Yeah, that seems right.

Comment: Thanks I just tried it and it works--had to tweak the 1 : -1 because it was in the wrong order but sorted  Thanks